# Where does Java Servlets and Applets run on?

Tags: java, applet

Where does Java Servlets and Applets run on? On server-side or Client-side?

Comment: Servlets on server. Applets on client.

Comment: Google broken again? The **definition** of those words would give you the answer...

Comment: Really?  7 Downvotes?  Was that really necessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Servlets run on the server side.

Applets run in the client browser.